# How to remove formatting from Google Table Visualization

Tags: formatting, google-visualization

I want to add a bar formatter on the sorted column of Google table viz. So when sorting changes from one column to another I need to remove formatting from my previous sorted column and put it on the new column. And since formatting is associated with data table, Is there any way to remove formating from the table without redrawing it? May be I am looking for a class like **"BarDeformat"**.